# What is the best way to log HTTP requests and limit it to certain contollers?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'd like to log HTTP requests for just one controller and exclude the rest of my controllers. I'd like to also use this for other future controllers that may need it. Can I achieve this through custom middleware? Is there something pre-built to perform this?

I have logged the incoming DTO, but I would like to log the HTTP request. I understand I can create Middleware to achieve this for all controllers, but I want to pick and choose which ones use it.

Comment: `.net`(framework) is the predecessor of `.net-core` as you can see in the tool-tip of the two contradicting tags - which on is yours?

Comment: .net-core, I updated it

Answer (score 2):

In .Net 6/7, you could log HttpRequest with app.UseHttpLogging() MiddleWare,and try to branch the pipeline with app.UseWhen（）

For your reqirement,I tried as below in Program.cs:

```
 builder.Services.AddHttpLogging(x => x.LoggingFields = HttpLoggingFields.RequestPropertiesAndHeaders);
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseWhen(x => x.Request.RouteValues["Controller"]?.ToString() == "Home",
        app => app.UseHttpLogging()
        );
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    app.Run();
```

in appSettings.json:

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware": "Information"
    }
  },
```

The Result:

[image]

You could check the documents related with [MiddleWare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#branch-the-middleware-pipeline-1)   and [HttpLogging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

You could also try to add filters to the default logger with:

```
builder.Logging.AddFilter(....)
```

and here's the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#filter-function) related

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with an action filter as well.

you just need to create a class derived from `ActionFilterAttribute`  and override the method `OnActionExecuting`  method.

```
public class LogActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        Console.WriteLine($"Request method: {request.Method}");
        ...//other logging
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

then you can use this action filter on the required controller or action method like `[LogActionFilter]`.

Answer (score 1):

Custom middleware is the best choice for this to log http request. You can handle http request as per the your requirement and logs the request and response for any specific controller based on incoming request inside the middle ware.
So I am suggesting to customer middleware.